# Plotting multiple normalized histograms along third axis

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I'd like to plot multiple histograms in a single plot, where the histograms are separated along a third axis.

For instance, let's say I'd like to plot the following two histograms (in reality, I'd like to plot something like 10 histograms at the same time):

[image]

and

[image]

They are generated by the following code:

```
histogram(points_inside1,100,'Normalization','pdf')
```

and

```
histogram(points_inside2,100,'Normalization','pdf')
```

where 'points_inside1' and 'points_inside2' are arrays with 10^5 entries.

I couldn't get [`bar3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) to work (I don't think it can take the normalized histograms as input).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this right, you need to first get the histogram data by `histcounts`, and then plot it with `bar3`:

```
% some data:
p1 = randn(1000,1)+2;
p2 = randn(1000,1);
% don't use too many bins:
bins = 10;
% get the histogram data:
[N1] = histcounts(p1,bins,'Normalization','pdf');
[N2] = histcounts(p2,bins,'Normalization','pdf');
% plot it:
bar3([N1.' N2.']);
```

However, You may still have a problem since the X-axis is not aligned between all the histograms, so you can use the `edges` of the combined histogram for all the others:

```
% get the histogram data:
[~,edges] = histcounts([p1;p2],bins,'Normalization','pdf');
[N1] = histcounts(p1,edges,'Normalization','pdf');
[N2] = histcounts(p2,edges,'Normalization','pdf');
% compute the correct X-tick values:
X = movmean(edges.',2);
% plot it:
b = bar3(X(2:end),[N1.' N2.']);
```

[image: 3D_hist]